# Duplicated rows on JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to join two (there is more, but I will use two as an example) tables stored on Azure SQL Server. Basically those are customer order data joined with delivery data to check if ordered amount was delivered etc. One table has some order info like orderID, lineItemID, order quantity, etc. and will have one row per line item in order. Another table can have more then one line for the same combination because in case of delivery in batches it will have one line for each delivery with aggregated amount of previous deliveries of line item on order.

In case there is more then one row of data, I'm interested only in the last one (where delivered amount will be max).

When I will just run a query to check if I will get only one row per order item on second table, everything seems to be working fine:

```
SELECT   
    lp.[OrderId]
   ,lp.[ItemId]
   ,lp.[DeliveredQty]
   ,lp.[someField1]
   ,lp.[someField2]
   ,lp.[someField3]
   ,lp.[someField4]
   ,lp.[someField5]
   ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER( 
                        PARTITION BY lp.[OrderId], lp.[ItemId] 
                        ORDER BY lp.[OrderId], lp.[ItemId], lp.[DeliveredQty] DESC 
                    ) AS "row"
FROM Delivery lp
WHERE lp.[OrderId] = '1234'
```

Above query is returning all the rows, but the ones I need will have [row] = 1 which I want to use to filter returned data.
[image: query result]

Yet when I will just copy and paste this query to the main query and add INTO to store its results in a temp table which I want to use for JOIN and add filter on [row] = 1 so basically I do this:

```
SELECT   
    lp.[OrderId]
   ,lp.[ItemId]
   ,lp.[DeliveredQty]
   ,lp.[someField1]
   ,lp.[someField2]
   ,lp.[someField3]
   ,lp.[someField4]
   ,lp.[someField5]
   ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER( 
                        PARTITION BY lp.[OrderId], lp.[ItemId] 
                        ORDER BY lp.[OrderId], lp.[ItemId], lp.[DeliveredQty] DESC 
                    ) AS "row"
INTO #tempTable
FROM Delivery lp
```

and I will run
`SELECT * FROM #tempTable WHERE [OrderId] = '1234'`
what I get as a result are the same rows I had previously, but all of them has **1** in the **[row]** column, where previously there were 1, 2, 3, ... for the same OrderId and ItemId.
[image: If queried into temp table]

I've tried also instead of using
`ROW_NUMBER()`
and
`PARTITION BY`
to use
`GROUP BY [OrderId], [ItemId]`
and `max()`
for other columns, but the result is the same. It works as a test query, and it doesn't work when I will use it to create temporary table for my
`JOIN`
.

I've even tried to
`ORDER BY lp.[OrderId], lp.[ItemId], lp.[DeliveredQty] DESC`
and
`SELECT DISTINCT * FROM`
first temp table to another one and use second one for
`JOIN`
, but this doesn't work either.

Thank you in advance for all your help!

Comment: I can't read that tiny image text.

Comment: i'm sorry but what you say isn't possible.. Please provide the whole sample script with some data rows so we can recreate the issue ourselves. Perhaps there are some spaces in your item ids, but impossible to say

Comment: When I run the query as a stand alone query it is working as expected, whenever I'm adding 
`INTO`
statement to store it in temporary table, it breaks.

Comment: yes, i read you, but as i said, that's not possible :) into #t doesn't change the underlying query, unless you also change something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard approach here would be to simply subquery your current query and then restrict to only row number values of 1:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        lp.[OrderId],
        lp.[ItemId],
        lp.[DeliveredQty],
        lp.[someField1],
        lp.[someField2],
        lp.[someField3],
        lp.[someField4],
        lp.[someField5],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY lp.[OrderId], lp.[ItemId] 
            ORDER BY lp.[OrderId], lp.[ItemId], lp.[DeliveredQty] DESC
        ) AS rn
    FROM Delivery lp
    WHERE lp.[OrderId] = '1234'
)

SELECT OrderId, ItemId, DeliveredQty, someField1, someField2, someField3,
       someField4, someField5
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

If you are running this only for reporting reasons, you could also simulate `QUALIFY` on SQL Server using `TOP 1 WITH TIES`:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
    lp.[OrderId],
    lp.[ItemId],
    lp.[DeliveredQty],
    lp.[someField1],
    lp.[someField2],
    lp.[someField3],
    lp.[someField4],
    lp.[someField5]
FROM Delivery lp
WHERE lp.[OrderId] = '1234'
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    PARTITION BY lp.[OrderId], lp.[ItemId] 
    ORDER BY lp.[OrderId], lp.[ItemId], lp.[DeliveredQty] DESC
);
```

Comment: Approach using 
`WITH`
I haven't tried before. Unfortunately, when I'm running it as a query it returns correct result (3 rows in this case), but as soon as I will just add INTO #tempTable - it's returning 4 rows :/

My query is building a table which is then used in Power BI.\

Comment: Sorry to hear this, my code should be working per your stated requirements.

Comment: I've just read on Microsoft's documentation that Common Table Expressions cannot be used together with INTO  statement. So probably this might be the issue.

Comment: Then just subquery your original query and add `WHERE "rows" = 1`

Comment: Thank You for your suggestions. It worked finally!

What I had to do is exactly use my first query as a sub-query in
`FROM`
statement of another
`SELECT [...] INTO`
statement. Then I got my deduplicated results I was looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately, what looked OK for single document, is not working when there is more then one. I've added updated info.

Comment: Unfortunately, editing and changing your question after others have answered and you have accepted is not allowed on this site.  If you revert your question to the original version, I will remove my downvote.

Comment: I've accepted after testing on single document case. It doesn't work after removing filter on single document, so the issue is not resolved. You can keep the down vote if you want, it's a free world.

Comment: That's fine, but the correct thing to do is ask a new question.  I won't change my answer, and, as your question has also been marked duplicate, it cannot receive any new answers.